# ajax request getting 'canceled' now that site is live

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

All of my AJAX requests were working perfectly fine when I had my new version in a sub directory of my site (www.staging.easyuniv.com). When I then moved the site located in staging into the main directory, making it live (www.easyzag.com), everything is working fine, however a couple of the AJAX requests that get sent come up as 'cancelled' when looking in the network tab of chrome dev tools.

[image: display]

Others, which send the request to the exact same API file, work completely fine. Also, if I copy the url it sends the request to, I get a valid response.

I tried to use the debugger and didn't really gain any insight. Also, there are no errors in the console.

Any ideas on what I should look into?

Thanks

EDIT: it no longer works on staging either, so it has to be something that changed in the upload. The only confusing part is that, like I said, some of the requests do work, only a the deals/randomActive doesn't work

Comment: are you seeing any wrong behavior?

Comment: Do any of the ajax calls get made when a link is clicked? Are you using Apache?

Comment: Firefox shows you are returning a HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently. I suspect that's the issue...

Comment: What do you mean by wrong behavior? Everything else is working properly. Just that one request. Firefox shows a moved permanently returning for what URL?

Comment: @AlecSanger not after a link, it just loads the data from the API as the page loads

Comment: anything that has /API/deals/...is showing as 301 status

Comment: This one is showing as not found 404 /api/deals/random

Comment: Try changing your url from `http://www.easyuniv.com/API/deals/randomActive/2/0/0` to:

`http://easyuniv.com/API/deals/randomActive/2/0/0`

Comment: if i put either of those into my address bar i get a result though. also - @Cocre8or API has to be capital

Comment: your right, that was it. @aquinas make an answer and i will select it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that your browser doesn't work the same way as making an ajax request. Your browser will follow 301s, but ajax requests won't do that automatically (at least they probably won't). See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pRvKz/

```
$.get("http://easyuniv.com/API/deals/randomActive/2/0/0",function(x){
    alert(x);
}).fail(function(){
    alert("oh no the non-www request failed");
});

$.get("http://www.easyuniv.com/API/deals/randomActive/2/0/0",function(x){
    alert(x);
}).fail(function(){
    alert("oh no the www request failed");
});
```

P.S. when making the above fiddle, I accidentally stumbled upon a SQL injection that you have. Please fix it before someone else finds it *yikes*.